# MongoDB not finding record by min date

Tags: mongodb

I have the following object in Mongo:

```
{
  "end" : new Date("Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT +00:00"),
  "start" : new Date("Mon, 01 Jan 0001 00:00:00 GMT +00:00"),.....
}
```

I want to return the record based on today's date:

```
 {"start" : {"$lt" : new Date()}, "end": {"$gt" : new Date()}}
```

This returns nothing.

I've tried just using the start date:

```
 {"start" : {"$lt" : new Date()}}
```

This returns nothing. However, this does work:

```
 {"start" : {"$gt" : new Date()}}
```

Equally, using `$lt` on the `end` field yields no result but `$gt` does.

Any ideas on why this behaviour is being exhibited?

Comment: what version of mongodb?

Comment: What's the min/max date range in MongoDB? Is there a limitation?

Comment: just update mongodb to 2.0 and rebuild indexes + and this issue will be solved :). @mnemosyn described issue very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Older versions of MongoDB have problems with dates before Unix Epoch (January 1st, 1970); queries crossing the epoch boundary don't return correct results.

There's a [thread on the newsgroup](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-dev/browse_thread/thread/30d27e5b6f926c1f) about this topic.

Bottom line: you should use a binary with version >= 2.0 and run

```
db.yourCollection.reIndex()
```

That will fix your indexes. Keep in mind that re-indexing on huge collections can take a lot of time.

Comment: That sounds like the issue - will give it a try and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript ISODate object stores the time in milliseconds from January 1, 1970.  The specification for the JavaScript Date class is here: http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.9  From this documentation, the earliest "legal" date is 01 January, 129 UTC.

d = new Date("Mon, 01 Jan 0001 00:00:00 GMT +00:00") is an invalid date object.  I believe the failing is in JavaScript, and not with MongoDB.  Different versions of the MongoDB shell handle invalid dates differently:

In 1.6:

```
> d = new Date("Mon, 01 Jan 0001 00:00:00 GMT +00:00")
"Invalid Date"
```

In 1.8 and 2.0:

```
> d = new Date("Mon, 01 Jan 0001 00:00:00 GMT +00:00")
ISODate("0NaN-NaN-NaNTNaN:NaN:NaNZ")
```

In 2.1:

```
> d = new Date("Mon, 01 Jan 0001 00:00:00 GMT +00:00")
ISODate("2001-01-01T00:00:00Z")
```

If a "legal" date object is created, your query will work as expected:

```
> db.time.save({ "end" : new Date("Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT +00:00"), "start" : new Date("Mon, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT +00:00")})
> db.time.find({"start" : {"$lt" : new Date()}, "end": {"$gt" : new Date()}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ed3fa4f89b8abdabefe1b5c"), "end" : ISODate("9999-12-31T23:59:59Z"), "start" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
```

All of this being said, as mnemosyn pointed out, it looks as though there was an issue with indexing dates in mongod that has now been resolved.  If possible, you should upgrade to 2.0+, and reindex if there is old index on dates.